# How do I display text for touch events in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, ios, d3.js

I have a map with areas on it where it displays text when the mouse hovers over it (using touchstart and touchend events). 
However, on my iPad the text does not display although the areas change color when I touch it.
Anyone know how to make it display the text?

```
 function create_canada(canada) {
 var provinces = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "provinces")
 .selectAll("path")
 .data(topojson.object(canada, canada.objects.provinces).geometries)
 .enter().append("path")
 .attr("class", "province")
 .attr("d", path)
 .style("fill", function(d) {
   return "#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  }) 
 .style("opacity","0.7")
 .on("touchstart", function(d) {
  colour = d3.select(this).style("fill");
  d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");
  }) // end mouseover
  .on("touchend", function(d) {
               d3.select(this).style("fill", function(d) {
                  return colour;
                }); // end mouseout
            }); // end var provinces
 provinces.append("svg:title") 
     .text(function(d) {
          return (d.id + " " + (get_Percapita(d)) + " per million"); // d.id is the Province name
          });

return provinces;
```

Comment: What browser are you using on your iPad? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: I've tried Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Sometimes when I touch the area for a longer period it selects some text above the chart put it doesn't display my popup text.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a *tspan in* your text like this :

```
<text><tspan>My text</tspan></text>
```

and the `touchstart` or `touchend` action should work fine.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan